# MediaPalyer seekTo() make audio start from the beginning

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have an audio with a SeekBar

what iam trying to do is draging  the seek bar to cretin position to make the media forward to that position using seekTo(position)

but what happen is the mediaPlayer starts the audio from beginning

this is My Code

```
    AudioSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ViewPagerAudioSeekBar);
    AudioSeekBar.setMax(99);
    AudioSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (fromUser) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
    } else {

    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation is specified that the seekTo parameter is the ms you want to jump, so what I gues you want to do is to:

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress*mediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)

Answer (score 0):

i solve it this way and its working fine

```
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

        int playPositionInMillisecconds = (MediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100)
                * seekBar.getProgress();

        mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);

    }
}
```